# Authentication by passport working in local but not in server

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, authentication, laravel-passport

So basically I have an application made with laravel and react which works fine and after I deployed it in the live server passport authentication is not working. Seems like the "Authorization" header is not going to the server and for that issue, I also changed my ".htaccess" file but no change.

This is my ".htaccess" file.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization HeaderRewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

#Https redirection 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) MY_SITE/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How do you know that the server isn't receiving the header? What did you use to check?

Comment: I used Insomnia (Postman Alternative) to see I am not receiving headers in response message.

Comment: The Authorization header isn't sent by the server in a response, it's only sent by the client to the server. Do you mean you're not receiving some other headers? Did you check something like whether your controller can access the `$request->header('Authorization')` value to see that you weren't getting the header in the request?

Comment: Yeah i checked that and it works fine on my local server but it's giving me problems in the live shared hosting server

Comment: Have you confirmed that mod_rewrite is enabled, AllowOverride (.htaccess) is allowed, and your hosting provider is using Apache?

Comment: I am trying to do that can you give me an example of how to do that??

Comment: Please update your post with more information about your server and the steps you've gone through to debug. Do you have command line access? OS? Hosting provider? I'm heading to bed, but somebody else might be able to help

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: @TravisBritz Yeah I figured it out so my hosting provider was blocking the headers into the shared hosting server. I contacted them and they fixed it for me. Everything was working fine from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to double check:

- mod_rewrite is enabled
- [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is enabled
- Your hosting provider is actually using Apache
- There are no CORS errors in the browser console

This *probably* is not the cause, but your Rewrite condition for the Authorization header is *slightly* different than what ships with the framework. Here is the default:

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: I searched for the solution and then updated my htaccess file accordingly.
Still when I try to hit the laravel passport protected path it is not accepting headers.